# Parsing Image from Excel Sheet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xlsx

The excel file will consist of images and record based on it, I am trying to parse it into JSON object but the image field will not be there, I am using xlsx library for parsing it. thanks for any help...

```
if(inputElement.files[0].name.match(/.(xlsx)$/i) || inputElement.files[0].name.match(/.(xls)$/i)){

    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(inputElement.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = (event)=>{

        let data = event.target.result;
        let workbook = XLSX.read(data,{type:"binary"});

        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(sheet => {

                let rowObject = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheet]);

                console.log(rowObject);

        });

   }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide rowObject. What's printed in the console? I assume there should be a blob with the image there...

Comment: The console log appears to skip the image column if there is an image, this is output

Comment: 0: {ID: 1234, Name: "Testing", __rowNum__: 2}
1: {ID: 5678, Image: "Image", Name: "Testing2", __rowNum__: 3}